# PostgreSQL Error: connection timeout expired

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a problem with PostgreSQL v16.  I installed it on Windows 11 to work with a Python project.  As a result, I created a server for myself, but when I try to start it, the endless loading crashes, and after the timeout expires, it asks again for a password, which was correct before.  I have already recreated the server several times, checked, everything is fine with the password itself.

This is what I get in the logs:

```
2023-09-26 11:12:13.742 EEST [63120] FATAL:  user "bimbax" did not pass authentication for the additional password
2023-09-26 11:12:13.742 EEST [63120] LOGS:  role "bimbax" not exists.
    Connection matched file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/data/pg_hba.conf" line 117: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256"`
```

Comment: That error message does not exist in the PostgreSQL code base, and the use of the word "user" for "role" is suspicious. Either that is not really PostgreSQL, or you are using some third-party extension.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add some details on how exactly you **1)** (re)created this setup (where you got the installer, what package manager you used, what commands) **2)** started it (config, commands) **3)** attempted to connect to the database (client application or library, steps in app/commands in cli/code)?